# How do I use the writeToFile method on an NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I would like to use a method (**writeToFile**) only available for NSDictionary to a NSMutableDictionary object. So, how do I convert this NSMutableDictionary object to NSDictionary?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

NSMutableDictionary inherits from NSDictionary. So, writeToFile should be available to both classes.

Answer (score 13):

For those coming here genuinely looking for conversion from NSMutableDictionary to NSDictionary :

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"value", @"key"] mutableCopy];

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:mutableDict]; //there you have it
```

Answer (score 7):

NSMutableDictionary is a subclass of NSDictionary, so the writeToFile method should be available for your object without having to do any casting or conversions.

Answer (score 6):

As already discussed here:

[How to save a NSMutableDictionary into a file in documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478440/how-to-save-a-nsmutabledictionary-into-a-file-in-documents/7478470#7478470)

you don't need to convert it.

But if you really want to, just use the `copy` method on your `NSMutableDictionary` or the `dictionaryWithDictionary:` method on `NSDictionary`.  Both provide an `NSDictionary` from an `NSMutableDictionary`.

Answer (score 3):

A NSMutableDictionary *is* a NSDictionary since it is a subclass.  Typically the relationship of a subclass to it's superclass is called: "is a".

Answer (score 1):

To address the actual question title and not the contents (since I searched for this Q) you can actually rely on `copyWithZone:` to get down to an Immutable Dictionary.

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
mutableDict[@"key"] = @"value";
NSDictionary *immutableDict = [mutableDict copy];
```