# saving changed text in textview loaded from NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, uitextview, nsmutabledictionary

I have a UITextView in a DetailViewController with some text which is loaded from a NSMutableDictionary in the MainViewController.  Here is the code for that;

```
- (void) coverflowView:(TKCoverflowView*)coverflowView coverAtIndexWasDoubleTapped:(int)index{

    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    if ((int)index == 0) {
        NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                        @"This is some text", @"textkey", nil];

               detailViewController.myDictionary = myDictionary;
    }
```

I have loaded the string from this into my DetailViewController with this code;

```
self.myText.text = [(NSMutableDictionary *)myDictionary objectForKey:@"textkey"];
```

Also in my viewDidLoad I have created a RightBarButton named 'Save' which I use to hide the keyboard when  the viewer is done editing. I would like this button to also save the changes the viewer enters into the UITextView (as well as the original text).
This is the code for the rightBarButton;

```
UIBarButtonItem *saveButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"Save"
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                   target:self
                                 action:@selector(textViewDidChange:)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton;
```

Lastly I have code which envokes the textVidewDidChange and hides the keyboard.  I am trying to also have it save the changes to the textView but it doesn't.

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView;
{
    if( textView == myText )
    [myDictionary setValue:myText.text forKey:@"textkey"];
    [myText resignFirstResponder];
   }
```

Can anyone help me accomplish this.  I simply want to save the changes to the UITextView back to the NSMutableDictionary.  (or maybe not so simply)

I have changed the button to 
`UIBarButtonItem *saveButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"Save"
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                   target:self
                                 action:@selector(didChangeValueForKey:)];

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton;`
```

and other code to ;

`-(void)didChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)key{
       NSError *error;

```
    [myDictionary setValue:[self myText].text forKey:@"textkey"];
[myText resignFirstResponder];

NSLog(@"%@", [myDictionary valueForKey:@"textkey"]);
```

}

My NSLog shows the changes but when I reopen the app they are gone, not saved.  Can one save directly to the NSMutableDictionary?
I read a lot on persistent data.  Thought NSData or Plist but try as I may not doing well.

Can someone suggest a good tutorial on this?

I looked at suggested link and added this (bold part) to my code.

`-(void)didChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)key{

```
/* NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[(NSMutableDictionary *)myDictionary objectForKey:@"textkey"]];*/
   NSError *error;


[myDictionary setValue:[self myText].text forKey:@"textkey"]; 
**[myDictionary writeToFile:@"textkey" atomically:YES];**

[myText resignFirstResponder];

NSLog(@"%@", [myDictionary valueForKey:@"textkey"]);
}`
```

As you can see I also tried getting the path using [NSHomeDirector] above and then replaced
@"textkey" with path.  I can still see the changes in NSLog (either way) but there is no change when I reload the view or relaunch the app.

I have change things so that I am saving a text file of the text in the textview with the name  gotten from the dictionary so that each time a different detailView is loaded depending on the image selected in the mainViewController.

This is my dictionary entry in the mainViewController;

`if ((int)index == 0) {
        NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      //here is where I want to access the text file name to load in the UITextView in my DetailView
                        @"first View Text", @"textkey2",

```
                 //This is where I give the text file of the changed text its name for each different view of the DetailView
                    @"first View Text", @"textkey3",nil];

           detailViewController.myDictionary = myDictionary;
}`
```

Next is the code I use to save the changes to the textView using the UIbarbuttonright

`- (void)saveAction:(id)sender {

```
[self.myText2 resignFirstResponder];

NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *documentTXTPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[(NSMutableDictionary *)myDictionary objectForKey:@"textkey3"]];
NSString *savedString = myText2.text;

NSLog(@"The Save file is:%@", savedString);

[savedString writeToFile:documentTXTPath atomically:YES
                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

}`

I have checked this and the file is saved in the documents folder under the name of First View Text and it does contain the changed text.

I am having problems loading the text file contents into the UITextView.
Using the code I have I get the path to the textkey2 object (First Text View) not the contents of the file.

```
`NSString *textName = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"textkey2"];
NSArray *paths2 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,   
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory2 = [paths2 objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *fullPath2 = [documentsDirectory2 stringByAppendingPathComponent:textName];
```

/* self.myText2.text = fullPath2;*/
    self.myText2.text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fullPath2       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];`

I replaced this last line with the one that isn't commented out and it works fine.  For anyone who want to know.

Comment: what issue exactly you are facing in this. Value is not replaced in the dictionary or something else....

Comment: when I add text to the textview and tap on the button the keyboard hide but if I exit the view and reload it the added text does not appear so the added text is not being saved.

Comment: are you sure your textViewDidChange method call?

Comment: When I put NSLog (@"%@", [myDictionary objectForKey:@"text key"]);     I get tableViewCoverflow (null)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement data persistence, e.g. saving the text into permanent storage that you can retrieve again when you reload the view later on.

Comment: I added some changes to bottom of my original post, please look.

Comment: I did a quick search and this is the first link I got: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478440/how-to-save-a-nsmutabledictionary-into-a-file-in-documents. That will save the contents of the dictionary into a file that you can specify. You can then load the contents of this particular dictionary later again when you need it.

Comment: changed some code above after looking at your suggestion, still no go.

Comment: I have done a whole rewrite on this and need some help loading file into UITextView.

Comment: Finally got this working by changing the last line of the code.